# Falha ao tentar aceder ao socket do servidor pela internet python3

Tags: python-3.x, servidor, socket

Boa tarde, 
Eu tenho umm problema, eu preciso de aceder há minha raspberry pi atraves de um socket porem quando eu testo localmente o programa funciona na perfeição, porem quando tento aceder a ele através da internet (tendo instalado na raspberry pi um dns dinamico assim ela esta sempre disponivel), mas eu não consigo entrar em contacto com o server pelo socket, eu consigo aceder a ele atraves do browser porem eu necessito para a minha aplicação que eu consiga aceder a ele a partir do socket.

o código do server está assim :

```
import socket
import threading
bind_ip="127.0.0.1"
bind_port=80
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
server.listen(1000)
def handle_client(client_socket):
    request=client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("[*]Recevid: ",request.decode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.send("teste".encode)
    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client,addr=server.accept()
    print("[*]Accepted connection from: ",addr[0]," ",addr[1])
    client_handler=threading.Thread(target=handle_client(client))
    client_handler.start()
```

eu mesmo ja tentei substituir o `127.0.0.1` por `192.168.1.3` ou ate mesmo pelo serviço do ddns porem nessas tentativas apenas obtive o erro que nao podia usar aquilo como ip do server se alguem me conseguir ajudar agradecia

Answer (score 0):

Se você consegue com o navegador, provavelmente então o problema está no client e não no seu server. Espero ter ajudado.